# Append Folder Name to 1st line in a file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, command

Consider I have a folder UNIX under Unix I have a XYZ.csv

```
"id","name","salary"--- Header
"1","Jon","1000"---line
```

output should be

```
"UNIX1","Jon","1000"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

See the below example:

```
kent$  pwd
/tmp/test/UNIX

kent$  head f
"id","name","salary"--- Header
"1","Jon","1000"---line

kent$  awk -v p="$(basename $PWD)" 'NR==2{sub(/"/,"&"p)}1' f
"id","name","salary"--- Header
"UNIX1","Jon","1000"---line
```

If it is not exactly what you want, add requirement in your question, instead of putting it in the comments.

Comment: Hi, /home/cg/root/FI100 this is the path under this there is a report.csv file i need 1st line of report.csv need to concatenated with FI100 ex if 1st line is "1","2","3" i need output as "FI1001","2","3"

Comment: it should do it for all nth line

Comment: @PrashanthPatil your requirement is `Append Folder Name to 1st line in a file in unix` If you want to apply it on all lines, change `NR==2` into `NR>1`